# Need help on laravel 8.. Failed to open stream error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My project shows this error after uploading on server...
file_put_contents(D:\laravel5\tryapp\storage\framework/sessions/BwYqrKfyavejZFnPUNb0ntJsKy5uMaoyCUzU7Srl): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
help.
[project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnZ1J.jpg)

Comment: This is a very broad question. Maybe you can add more details. The only thing I can get from your question is the use of both forward and backward slashes in the path. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: My original project exists in D drive inside laravel5 folder... But thats just the name of folder. The laravel version i am using is ^8. Now everything is perfect on local server but as i uploaded it into a subdomain to live check... This error message is showing up. Some how it is still picking up the localhost's storage location... As one can see the system path mentioned in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou all for Responding back....|| I figured out the problem...Laravel8 creates a "config.php" file inside folder bootstrap/cache/
This "config.php" file has " $path => D://Laravel8//...." set to The local (C:/> D:/> E:/> Etc)Drive where orginally the project is created when under development Mode(Localhost).

Conclusion:  This "config.php" file in Folder Path:" bootstrap/cache/ " needs to be deleted.
|| ...Next...
Move .htaccess file in out of public folder into Root Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Also try

```
rm public/storage
rm -rf public/storage
php artisan storage:link
```

And clear

```
php artisan clear-compiled &&
php artisan auth:clear-resets &&
php artisan cache:clear &&
php artisan config:clear &&
php artisan route:clear &&
php artisan view:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the permission of the `storage` folder.

`sudo chmod 777 storage/ -R`